# Node js "request" module. Issues with "get" and the return values

Tags: javascript, node.js

currently trying to get a response from this api: 'https://owlbot.info/api/v2/dictionary/WORD?format=json' which validates whether a word exists or not.

I am attempting to use the node js 'request' module to do this. If a word does not exist it returns an empty list, otherwise it returns the description of the word.

JS Code

```
var url = 'https://owlbot.info/api/v2/dictionary/' + words[i] + '?format=json';

console.log("URL: " + url);

request.get({
        url: url,
        json: true,
        headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
        }, (err, res, data) => {
            console.log("STATUSCODE: " + res.statusCode);
            console.log("BODY: " + data);
        });
```

However, the response always returns an empty response in the body despite a successful response code: Terminal output is:

STATUSCODE: 200

BODY:

I tried making a call to the API using pythons request module, which worked as expected. If there is something missing, could someone let me know?

I have read other similar questions on here and tried the solutions but no luck!

Comment: It returns a proper response with data dictionary. You need to read it properly.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: I am saying that the code is correct and it works at my end. Check your words list and remaining code.